# Is it possible to show a double integral from the product of two?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, display

I have two identical integrals here.
If I multiply them by each other is it possible that a double integral will result ?

1)
`Integrate[t^(x - 1)/E^t, {t, 0, Infinity}]*Integrate[s^(x - 1)/E^s,  {s, 0, Infinity}]`

`ConditionalExpression[Gamma[x]^2, Re[x] > 0]`

2)

`Integrate[(t^(x - 1)*s^(x - 1))/E^(t + s), {s, 0, Infinity},  {t, 0, Infinity}]`

`ConditionalExpression[Gamma[x]^2, Re[x] > 0]`

3. ..not derived with MMA

$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-s} s^{x-1} \, ds \left(\int_0^{\infty } e^{-t} t^{x-1} \, dt\right)=\int _0^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty }e^{-(s+t)} s^{x-1} t^{x-1}dtds$

`Integrate[t^(x - 1)/E^t, {t, 0, Infinity}]*Integrate[s^(x - 1)/E^s,  {s, 0, Infinity}] == Integrate[(t^(x - 1)*s^(x - 1))/E^(t + s),  {s, 0, Infinity}, {t, 0, Infinity}]`

`ConditionalExpression[True, Re[x] > 0]`

Comment: As the integrand separates, the integrals can be evaluated separately and the individual  results multiplied.

Comment: @Daniel Huber, thanks The question is of MMA (can) show a double integral out of two separated integrals directly.

Comment: That would not be very clever. A double integral is much more complicated than the product of 2 single integrals.

Comment: I cannot figure out what exactly is the question. Are you asking whether a product of symbolic integrals will be transformed automatically to a multiple integral? If that is the question, the answer is no.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, thanks.That's too much asked then.
I follow a prove and i know that the double integral equals the two single integrals
So i can go further..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just want to display it. In the following I used [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) as in another recent answer to one of your questions. You might want to look up [`HoldForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) and [`Defer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) for display purposes.

Relevant comment: though a nicer display might be aesthetically pleasing, I am not a big fan of it for practical purposes and long computations.

Define the following:

```
int[f_, g_, t1_, t2_, s1_, s2_] := 
 Inactive[Integrate][f, {t, t1, t2}] Inactive[Integrate][
    g, {s, s1, s2}] = 
  Inactive[Integrate][f g, {t, t1, t2}, {s, s1, s2}]
```

For your example

```
int[t^(x - 1)/E^t, s^(x - 1)/E^s, 0, Infinity, 0, Infinity]
```

> [image: doubleintegral]

If you want to calculate it now

```
Assuming[Re[x] > 0, 
 Activate@int[t^(x - 1)/E^t, s^(x - 1)/E^s, 0, Infinity, 0, Infinity]]
```

> [image: res]

Comment: bmf ,thanks. With this double integral i can try to follow the proof of Legendre's Duplicatie Formula ( known by MMA ?)

Comment: @janhardo it's not clear to me what the additional question is to be honest. I just provided an answer for the question in the OP.

Comment: bmf, the additional question has not been formulated yet, but will pop up as I follow the proof further regarding integration techniques.

Comment: @janhardo perhaps you'd be interested in knowing that on SE in general each post should be self-contained as well as pose a single question. The reasoning is fairly simple in my eyes, if you keep adding stuff as questions and sub-questions a post will never be completed. You might want to keep that in mind

Comment: bmf  , Good that you pointed that out to me 
I then ask a new question about the topic I am working on then in a new post.

Comment: @janhardo thanks. Out of curiosity, the original question was about the display of a product of integrals as an integral of products, right? Or did I misunderstand what you wanted?

Comment: bmf -See @ daniel lichtblau : his answer: I cannot figure out what exactly is the question. Are you asking whether a product of symbolic integrals will be transformed automatically to a multiple integral? If that is the question, the answer is no.
Yes, that is the question.
Hope it is now clear.

Comment: @janhardo I see. Well I think I have demonstrated how to force Mathematica to show you the output as you want and how to make it active again for calculation purposes.

Comment: bmf- thanks for your effort, i will study it futher.
Again Inactive command here, remarkable.

Comment: @janhardo glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 4):

Double integral shows the same result as the product of singl integrals

```
{ Integrate[t^(x - 1)/E^t, {t, 0, Infinity}]*Integrate[s^(x - 1)/E^s,  {s, 0,Infinity}],
Integrate[t^(x - 1)/E^t s^(x - 1)/E^s, {s, 0, Infinity}, {t, 0, Infinity}]}

(*{ConditionalExpression[Gamma[x]^2, Re[x] > 0], 
ConditionalExpression[Gamma[x]^2, Re[x] > 0]}*)
```

Comment: thanks . It is clear to me that this is equal 
Can MMA symbolically make a double integral out of 2 integrals, that's really the question.